# how to search string value in different datetime format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I try to execute SQL select query given below. Tarih is a `datetime` field. Tarih in table: `2013-01-09 00:00:00.000` 
but my search value is `09.01.2013`.

```
select * from [BankaEntegrasyonEslesmeyenler] as x  where x.Tarih='09.01.2013'
```

> 99    6631    220220059   BÜLENT  ÖZCAN
>     28.3200 2831.5500   **2013-01-09 00:00:00.000** TL  8

Comment: have you tried casting '09.01.2013' as a datetime? that way you can match formats.

Comment: A different format? If you are saving dates in your database in anything other than `DATETIME` fields, you are doing it wrong. `DATETIME` has an internal representation - not a format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM [BankaEntegrasyonEslesmeyenler] AS x  WHERE CONVERT (CHAR(10), x.Tarih, 104) = '09.01.2013'
```

format the date in `dd.mm.yyyy` and compare date without time.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your date value as parameter or in the universal ISO format such as 
yyyymmdd, e.g.

'20130109'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 3) AS [DD/MM/YY]
```

selects the date in `dd/mm/yy` format

Answer (score 0):

You are confused on how it is stored.  2013-01-09 00:00:00.000 is just the default display format.

If you want that format then try this

```
select CONVERT ( char(10) , getdate() , 104 )

select CONVERT ( char(10) , x.Tarih , 104 ) from ....
```

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)